# Personality Test MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement, switch-statement, strtok

I am sorry for asking this guys, but this problem has been the bane of my existence for a week. I should have been able to figure it out by now, but I can't seem to get it to work. What I need to do is code for a personality test. It's based on this circle:

```
                            1
                        10        2

                     9               3

                     8               4

                        7         5
                             6
```

So I already have my inputs given to me. I have three of them: type1, pVec1, and subType1. pVec is a vector that I am assuming I have to index. type1 is given to me as either my dominant or recessive trait. What I have to do with that, is determine what my other traits are. If they gave me my dominant trait, the first letter would be capitalized. If it's recessive, it's lowercase. Dominant and recessive traits are always opposite of one another. If I have a dominant personality type 3, my recessive would be type 8 (using the circle). Furthermore, my wing personality types are based off of my dominant type. They are the numbers to the left and right (in this case, 2 and 4 would be my wing personality types).The subtype just tells me whether or not to add something about my dominant type.

```
 Test Cases:
      type1 = 'helper';
      pVec1 = ['Reformer Helper Achiever Individualist Dreamer Investigator    
               Loyalist Enthusiast Challenger Peacemaker'];
    subType1 = 'alone';
[dom1, rec1, wings1] = personalityTest(type1,pVec1,subType1);
      dom1 > 'Loyalist_a'
      rec1 => 'Helper'
       wings1 => 'Enthusiast Investigator'
```

So I have to get it to do stuff like that. So far I have:

```
 function[dominant, recessive, wings] = personalityTest(type, pVec, subtype)
 type_list = strsplit(pVec);

 position = find(strcmpi(type, type_list), 1, 'first');
 dominant = upper(type(1));
 dominant = char(type);
 recessive = lower(type(1));
 recessive = char(type);
 switch type
case recessive
    dominant = position + 5;
case dominant
    recessive = char(dominant - 5);
 end

 leftwing = char(dominant + 1);
 rightwing = char(dominant - 1);

 wings = [leftwing rightwing];
 if strcmp(subtype, 'alone')
    dominant = [dominant '_a'];
elseif strcmp(subtype, 'smallGroup')
    dominant = [dominant, '_s'];
else 
    dominant = [dominant, '_1'];
end
```

My function keeps keeps giving me a blank for dominant (or just _a). How do I fix that? I want it to give me the word in the fifth position.

Comment: Now that neuroscience is showing its colors with `"personality test"` thing!

Comment: Naw man, that's Psychology

Comment: Aren't those related somehow on the brain/mind stuffs? :)

Comment: Use `strsplit` instead of that 10 line `strtok` mess.  Then, `find(strncmpi(type, type_list), 1, 'first')` to get the numeric value of the matching one.  Add 5 if it is recessive, to get dominant.  Add and subtract 1 to get wings.

Comment: Would type_list be my pVec then? and what would 'first' be? Just that string?

Comment: `type_list` would be the cell array of split strings as cells - `type_list = strsplit(pVec)`.

Comment: Oh. I have yet to learn about cell array, but that makes sense :)

Comment: @BenVoigt How would I turn that into an if-statement though? I'm a little confused by the structure. I need it to know it's recessive, but when i tried to do that in my code before, it flagged the word recessive

Comment: When you update your code, please write at the end of your question EDIT: <<whatever was edited>>. Otherwise the comments don't make sense for a new reader. I had to search in edit history what was the "10 line mess of strtok".

Comment: I put it in there last time, but I think it got overridden. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stepping through your code will help reveal the errors to you.

```
type = 'helper';
pVec = ['Reformer Helper Achiever Individualist Dreamer Investigator    
          Loyalist Enthusiast Challenger Peacemaker'];
subType = 'alone';
```

Executing the follow lines of your function

```
 type_list = strsplit(pVec);

 position = find(strcmpi(type, type_list), 1, 'first');
 dominant = upper(type(1));
 dominant = char(type);
 recessive = lower(type(1));
 recessive = char(type);
```

Results in `dominant` and `recessive` being set to these values

```
dominant = 'helper'
recessive = 'helper'
```

The intention here, I think, is to determine if the first character of the type string is uppercase or lowercase. In other words, we want a `True` or `False` value for `dominant` or `recessive`.

The function `upper()` converts an input `string` or `char` into uppercase. To check if the first character is uppercase or lowercase, try

```
dominant  = type(1) == upper(type(1))
recessive = type(1) == lower(type(1))
```

The assignments

```
dominant = char(type);
recessive = char(type);
```

are unnecessary (they overwrite your previous computations!).

Now the next lines of code will be closer to producing the correct output.

```
switch type
case recessive
    dominant = position + 5;
case dominant
    recessive = char(dominant - 5);
end
```

Three (maybe four) problems here.

1. `dominant = position + 5`. If `position` had a value of `9`, then `dominant` would equal `14`. Since the intention here is to index into the type list with `dominant`, you could potentially incur an array index out of bounds error. The way to fix this is to use the modulus (remainder) function, i.e. `dominant = (position + 4) % 10 + 1`. The remainder function is basically "What is the remainder of `(p + 5)` after dividing by `10`. The weird 1 and 4 are to keep the range of values possibly assigned to `dominant` to be within [1, 10].
2. If the personality traits vector (`pVec`) is always going to be length `10`, then hardcoding the 5 into the computation is okay. However, if the length of `pVec` can vary, then you need to determine the correct value to increment position by. If the length is even, then that should be `length(pVec)/2`.
3. The line `recessive = char(dominant - 5)` would evaluate as `recessive = char('helper' - 5)` in your current iteration of code. This doesn't really make sense as you are subtracting an integer from a string and then casting to a string again. Instead, compute the index of the recessive trait in the type list. This is exactly the same procedure as outlined in 2.
4. Using variable names that indicate what they do will help you think more clearly about your code.
5. The goal is to use `dominant` and `recessive` as indexes into `type_list`. You are forgetting to set 1 of the 2 indexes in each of the switch cases.

Next lines of code:

```
leftwing = char(dominant + 1);
rightwing = char(dominant - 1);
```

Index into `type_list` to get the correct values for the left and right wings. Be careful of array index out of bounds errors.

Next lines:

```
wings = [leftwing rightwing];
if strcmp(subtype, 'alone')
    dominant = [dominant '_a'];
elseif strcmp(subtype, 'smallGroup')
    dominant = [dominant, '_s'];
else 
    dominant = [dominant, '_1'];
end
```

Again, indexing issues. Fix these and you're home free.